# Sharepoint 2007 to 2010 conversion and authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net, claims-based-auth, adfs

I'm consulting on a project that needs help passing authenticated user to other .Net applications on the same domain from Sharepoint to standard .Net & classic asp sites.  Currently in SP 2007, the .ASPXAUTH cookie gets written and can be accessed through the membership provider in an ASP.Net website via:

```
Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString()
```

In 2010, it's using claims based (federated) and writing a FEDAUTH cookie.  I need to upgrade these other subdomain deployments to be able to access the cookie credentials the same way that the one above is and this method is not working for the new cookie.  Any ideas?  I'm not a SP developer... I'm mainly standard .Net, so more info about SP is beyond me.

EDITS:
I've done some more research and it seems that one suggestion is to use a security token service (STS) and then use the FedUtil to redo my apps to authenticate to it.  Is there already an STS being published with the Sharepoint application for me to use?  I'm going to assume that connecting to this will be difficult from the 1 classic asp site that is still out there, but good for the .Net deployments.

More research, there seems to be a Claims aware .Net web application project in WIF download.  Is this just a prebuilt version of what I need to add to my web.config to make it claims aware?  Also, does SP2010 automatically include the WIF and ADFS 2?  The more I read, the more this sounds like a lot of server infrastructure upgrades and that's not something I'm going to have control over.  I really need to know if SP2010 is already using all the tools I need/found and how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good article here: [Configuring SharePoint 2010 and ADFS v2 End to End](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/30/configuring-sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-v2-end-to-end.aspx)
.

SP 2010 includes an STS but there is no GUI as there is for ADFS, It's all PowerShell.

When you create a claims-aware SP web application, it automatically does the FedUtil stuff for you. In SP, it's all under the hood. SP 2010 does NOT include ADFS. You need Windows Server 2008 R2 (preferably) and ADFS v2.0 is a separate download.

SP only does authorisation based on claims. You still need ADFS to authenticate.

The claims-aware web app. in WIF gives you the plumbing and displays the claims but you still need to do the FedUtil part to "bind" to ADFS. Refer [How to: Build an ASP.NET Relying Party Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517296.aspx)